# Windows 7 64-bit HTML content being rendered as text

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, html, desktop-gadget

Odd problem that I noticed one day; applications that use HTML or some XML variant to render content now have that content displayed as text, such as desktop gadgets & computer management.  I have linked a screenshot to better explain the situation.

1. The "Extended" services view is messed up, "Standard" works fine though.

   [image]
2. A portion of my desktop where a gadget is supposed to be displayed:

   [image]

Any ideas to where I should look for a problem, i.e corrupt DLL, registration of a control etc would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
I tried "removing" IE8 from "Turn Windows features on or off", followed by a required restart, turned it back on, followed by a required restart.  Nothing changed; various applications that use web content still display source code.  This is a serious problem now, because a plugin I use in Eclipse is also displaying code instead of various screens.

Comment: That's nutty.  If I had to take a shot in the dark I'd say a .NET update probably broke it, but wow...I've never seen this before.  CRAAZY.

Comment: Going out on a limb, I'd say your HTML renderer is broken :-). But seriously, try removing and reinstalling Internet Explorer 8. It's a wild shot in the dark, but it may be related to the registry associations with HTML or XML files.

Comment: @Randolph: You can't remove IE8 on Windows 7. (That's the base installed version)

Comment: Can't you? On my install of Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, I can go into "Turn Windows features on or off" and remove `Internet Explorer 8` quite easily. It's in the Control Panel, under `Programs and Features`.

Comment: What's even more interesting is that turning it off prompts you with "Some programs that depend on Internet Explorer 8 might not function properly", which is what I was going for: perhaps removing and re-adding it will kick the registry into recognising the correct DLLs or something. But as I said in the first place, it's a wild shot in the dark.

Comment: IE 8 x86 & x64 work fine as browsers.  Gonna compile a small app with an IE HTML control and see if it works.  Dunno if there is a simple way to *really* uninstall IE so that a re-install will reconnect the broken bits but I'll try that too, thanks Randolph.

Comment: IWebBrowser, i.e EAB22AC0-30C1-11CF-A7EB-0000C05BAE0B from shdocvw.dll works fine "out of the box", so its probably some other control that's messing up. I do not want to end up re-installing Windows at the moment; this machine is needed for work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed after I installed the Internet Explorer 9 release candidate.